# python syntax error in script, fine in REPL

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I put this python code into the REPL for python (the interactive shell), it works as expected:

```
>>> def get_header():
...     return (None,None,None)
... 
>>> get_header()
(None, None, None)
```

Note that the return statement is indented by four spaces, and I have checked to ensure there are no extraneous spaces.

when I put the **exact** same code into a python script file and execute it, I get the following error:

```
./test.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 1: `def get_header():'
```

**WHY?**

EDIT: this is the *exact* contents of test.py, white spaces and all:

```
def get_header():
    return (None,None,None)

get_header()
```

I have verified that the above script (test.py) does yield the above error as it above stands.

Comment: Please post the exact contents of test.py, indentation and all.

Comment: Maybe something in lines 1-4?

Comment: I call shenanigans. Post at least lines 1 through 6 of your test.py file.

Comment: call it with `python test.py` . As one of the answers suggests, you are missing the shebang line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that you don’t have anything telling `bash` that this is a Python script, so it tries to execute it as a shell script, then throws an error when the syntax isn’t right.

What you need is to start the file with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line, telling it what it should be run with. So your file becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_header():
    return (None, None, None)

print get_header()
```